# In Angular 7 version Lazy Loading is not working

Tags: webpack, angular-routing, angular-router, angular7

I have updated my angular 6 version to angular 7 version. Now I am getting error when I try to navigate to 'http://localhost:4200/pages'. I am use lazy loading route concept in my application.

Error:-

> core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './Pages/Test/Test.module'
>   Error: Cannot find module './Pages/Test/Test.module'
>       at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:5
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:14143)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
>       at zone.js:872
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14134)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:5
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:14143)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)

### app-routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes} from '@angular/router';

export const AppRoutes : Routes = [
 {
  path : '',
  redirectTo: 'test',
  pathMatch: 'full',
 }
 {
  path: 'test',
  loadChildren: './Pages/test/test.module#TestModule'
 }      
]
```

Tell me, how to solved this error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After trying many changes, I found that my app.routing.ts should be like this:-

```
import { TestModule } from './Pages/test/test.module';

 export const AppRoutes : Routes = [
 {
  path : '',
  redirectTo: 'test',
  pathMatch: 'full',
 }
 {
  path: 'test',
  loadChildren: () =>  TestModule
 }      
]
```

After changes this works perfect for me.

Comment: Can you explain why or maybe give us a link to point where you found the answer ?

Comment: but when using this approach, things actually work but I am unable to make a prod build

Comment: Importing module break lazy loading, that's why it solved your initial problem with lazy loading

Comment: My comment was downvoted and removed, do not know why. Again, this solution is wrong. As @Hayha already mentioned, this is breaking lazy loading. When importing the module in the first line, the module is eagerly loaded. This should not be the accepted answer because it is misleading. Should this comment be removed once again, will have to contact StackOverflow directly. Please see my answer for a correct solution.

Comment: This answer is wrong as it does not in any way use lazy loading which was the intention.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is wrong and should actually be removed because it is misleading and when adopted, can lead to unexpected behavior and performance issues. The problem is that as soon as you import a module (first line in your code) like `import { TestModule } from './Pages/test/test.module';` the module will be loaded directly (eagerly). regardless of what you provide to `loadChildren`.

Please see a correct approach below:

```js
 export const AppRoutes : Routes = [
 {
  path : '',
  redirectTo: '/test',
  pathMatch: 'full',
 }
 {
  path: 'test',
  loadChildren: () => import('./Pages/test/test.module').then(mod => mod.TestModule)
  }      
]
```

Like this, the module gets imported (loaded) only when the provided function in `loadChildren` is called, which happens only when you navigate to `/test`. As you see, i removed the initial import `import { TestModule } from './Pages/test/test.module';` from the beginning of the code.

Hope this helps!

-Ivan

Comment: Worked very well! Thanks. I agree the current answer needs to be removed as its not in any way lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

For starts you **should always** place the paths starting with the **most restrictive ones first** and eventually the default path... Then, you didn't share your module code, we can only assume that you readily have a **test-routing.module.ts** file that correctly defines the components to load when the paths in that module are called/matched.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes} from '@angular/router';

export const AppRoutes : Routes = [
 {
  path: 'test',
  loadChildren: './Pages/test/test.module#TestModule'
 }, {
  path : '',
  redirectTo: 'test',
  pathMatch: 'full',
 }      
]
```

**test-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { TestComponent } from "./test/test.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: TestComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TestRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to eagerly load modules with a function reference when AOT enabled for Angular 7, you need to create an NgFactory module as you can see from this PR - https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13909.

A working solution for me was creating a clone of my module and adding `.ngfactory` postfix to the filename and also adding `NgFactory` postfix to the module class name.

```js
import { FirstPageModuleNgFactory } from '../pages/first-page.module.ngfactory';
import { SecondPageModuleNgFactory } from '../pages/second-page.module.ngfactory';

export function loadFirstPageModule() {
    return FirstPageModuleNgFactory;
}

export function loadSecondPageModule() {
    return SecondPageModuleNgFactory;
}

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomePageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'first',
                pathMatch: 'full',
            },
            {
                path: 'first',
                loadChildren: loadFirstPageModule,
            },
            {
                path: 'second',
                loadChildren: loadSecondPageModule,
            },
        ],
    },
];
```